# Halo Reach Credits custom games

Tags: halo-reach

I was at a LAN party at one of my friends house last night where we played 50+ custom game matches. Mainly Infection.

After every matches was over, me and only one of my other buddies got only 50 or less credits. While the other 7 people in the group got 100 - 1000 credits every match. I was top player on several occasions and still only got 50 or less credits. I even had more medals in a few matches compared to my friends that were getting more points.

I figure there may be a glitch because me and the one other buddy were on a separate hub than the rest of the group, but we still played the matches just fine.

Why was I not receiving 100-1000 credits like everyone else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is only a theory, but were the ones that were getting reduced credits xbox live profiles?

If a profile is an online one (AKA a gold subscription I believe) then they work on a different credit scale than that of an offline account. This is done so that offline accounts can experience all the joys of the armory easier, and online accounts can't abuse offline play to max out credits easy.

This is what I'm basing this theory on:

> On a similar note, I’ve been seeing
>   some chatter about the prospect of
>   mass quantity credit dumps that can be
>   earned through offline play in various
>   game modes. Some of the laziest among
>   us are no doubt already plotting out
>   their path of least resistance,
>   thinking of ingenious new ways to
>   rubber band a controller to achieve a
>   Zen like state of ridiculous
>   effortlessness.
>
> Not so fast. When you escort your
>   offline profile into the wonderful
>   world of Xbox LIVE, our servers will
>   identify your newly connected status
>   and instantly notify you that our
>   online credit scale operates on a
>   completely different level. (That
>   fizzle sound you’re hearing is
>   probably your boosters running out of
>   fuel in an oxygen starved environment.
>   Don’t look down, RocketMan.)
>
> If you choose to remain offline with
>   your decked out profile, you get to
>   keep your ducats and your duds with no
>   questions asked. But should you opt to
>   take this party online, your credits
>   will be reduced significantly and any
>   Armory items that you had previously
>   earned (for which you no longer meet
>   the minimum online credit or rank
>   requirements) will be righteously
>   revoked.
>
> Of course, the credit reduction that
>   occurs when you make the move into
>   cyberspace is completely by design.
>   For players without a connection to
>   the outside world, the system is
>   simply accelerating the credits being
>   awarded to allow them to experience
>   the Armory at a realistically
>   achievable (but decidedly lonely)
>   offline pace. For those who opt for a
>   more social experience, the grind is a
>   little more protracted, but still
>   profoundly fun.

Source: http://www.bungie.net/News/content.aspx?type=topnews&link=BWU_090310

Comment: That makes complete sense. My other buddies were silver members that were getting more credits.

Answer (score 1):

- Online = 60 credits an hour without factored variables.
- Offline = 1000 credits an hour, no variables.
- Offline with an online account = 60 credits, no change.